# How can I make a div be responsive within another responsive div without media queries?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have a square div that is responsive (it remains a square in all devices). I need to add another div inside it, and I need it to be responsive as well. I'm not achieving this by any means and I don't think I need media queries for this. I'm clearly doing something wrong but just can't pin it.

This is what I need to achieve:

[image]

Here's my code or my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/bGEqEWW?editors=1100)

```css
.image-exists {
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-image: url(https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Finding-homes-for-your-kittens-1.png);
        border: 2px solid #8ABE57;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }

    .cover-image-flag:before {
        content: "Text here";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    left:0;
        background: #8ABE57;
        padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-6 img-holder cover-image-flag">
  <a href="#" class="delete-img-button">
    <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x delete-img-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-times fa-stack-1x delete-img-icon"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="image-exists"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create two `divs` inside one `div` and do the following:

```css
.img-holder {
  background: #8ABE57;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 0.35rem;
}

.image-exists {
        position:relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-image: url(https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Finding-homes-for-your-kittens-1.png);
        
    }
.cover-image-text {  
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    background: #8ABE57;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-2 img-holder cover-image-flag">
  <a href="#" class="delete-img-button">
    <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x delete-img-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-times fa-stack-1x delete-img-icon"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="image-exists">
    <div class="cover-image-text">Test</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This works. Where is the green background coming from?

Comment: As you can see , i have added that in .img-holder class.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure this solution will work, since I have this structure on my site: https://imgur.com/th94Gjc and as you can see all the divs are squared and I need a text within them. So I can't have a green background. Any thoughts?

Comment: then simply you can remove background, and add where you need.That will not affect the structure.

Comment: Ok,I'll try that and let you know :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216340/discussion-between-paula-and-suraj-gupta).